# Mysql PHP query - add to previous value

Tags: mysql

I'd like to ask, what is PHP query to update a value in mysql table not by replacing it but by adding a new number to existing one.
Let's say:

> db=Items, table=products, col=product_name, col=qty.

I want to find

product 'laptop' qty='1' and update qty by adding 2 more with using a variable.

Thx.

Comment: Show your code. What did you tried so far?

Comment: This problem is resolved for me. I'm doing my first php ecommerce simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql part is

```
  update products
  set qty = qty+2
  where product_name ='laptop'
```